# Parse nested data from JSON using Codable

Tags: json, swift, struct, codable, decodable

I am trying to parse nested data from JSON response but not getting success. Below is what i tried so far and the json response trying to parse.

// JSON

```
 {
"statusCode": 200,
"success": true,
"data": {
    "tDetail": [
        {
            "roleId": null,
            "id": 34,
            "userId": 126,
            "catId": null,
            "importId": null,
            "name": "My task from postman",
            "myday": 1,
            "important": 0,
            "completed": 0,
            "dateCreated": "2020-02-10T09:05:04.000Z",
            "dateModified": "2020-02-10T09:05:04.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "steps": [],
    "files": [],
}
}
```

// Struct

```
struct MyDayAndTaskDetails: Codable
{
let data : [MyTaskDetail]
}

struct MyTaskDetail : Codable {
let roleId, taskId, userId, catId, important, completed, recurring, myday : Int?
let repeatType, name, duedate, reminder, frequency, weekdays, notes, baseurl : String?
let steps : [Steps]
let files : [Files]

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case taskId = "id"
       case userId = "userId"
    case roleId = "roleId"
    case catId = "catId"
    case myday = "myday"
       case name = "name"
       case notes = "notes"
       case duedate = "duedate"
       case reminder = "reminder"
       case recurring = "recurring"
       case repeatType = "repeatType"
       case important = "important"
       case completed = "completed"
    case frequency = "frequency"
    case weekdays = "weekdays"
    case baseurl = "baseurl"
    case steps = "Steps"
    case files = "Files"

   }
}

struct Steps : Codable {
let stepName : String?
let status, stepId : Int?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case stepName = "stepName"
       case status = "status"
       case stepId = "stepId"
   }
}

struct Files : Codable {
let fileName : String?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case fileName = "fileName"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one level

```
struct MyDayAndTaskDetails: Codable {
    let data : Detail       
}

struct Detail: Codable {
     let tDetail: [MyTaskDetail]
     let steps : [Steps]
     let files : [Files]
}
```

and so on

Comment: I got your point, can you please confirm whether steps and files are correct?

Comment: @iPhone7 Please have a closer look at the JSON. You see immediately that `steps`/`files` and `userID` etc. are vertically on different levels.

Comment: @iPhone7 Sorry I missed those 2 but that wasn't really the main point of the answer anyway. Answer updated

Comment: Hi, can you please guide me before i ask question:
func getTypeAPI(urlString: String, header: HTTPHeaders, completion: @escaping (MyDayAndTaskDetails?) -> Void) {

Comment: In above comment, Can we pass the the name of Struct as parameter at runtime rather than defining there because else i have to create separate functions for all structs when calling api. Hope i made my point clear.

Comment: @iPhone7, It is better if you post this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this structs, below structs are sufficient for given json. If you have more keys in your json then you can add them into their respective structs.

```
struct MyDayAndTaskDetails : Codable {
    let data : Task?
    let statusCode : Int?
    let success : Bool?
}
struct Task : Codable {
    let files : [Files]?
    let steps : [Steps]?
    let tDetail : [TDetail]?
}


struct TDetail : Codable {
    let catId : String?
    let completed : Int?
    let dateCreated : String?
    let dateModified : String?
    let id : Int?
    let importId : String?
    let important : Int?
    let myday : Int?
    let name : String?
    let roleId : String?
    let userId : Int?
}

struct Steps : Codable {
    let stepName : String?
    let status: Int?
    let  stepId : Int?
}

struct Files : Codable {
    let fileName : String?
}
```

And decode data with

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(MyDayAndTaskDetails.self, from: data)
```

Comment: thanks got, jus tell me one thing what difference will be there if i use let files : [Files]? or let files : [String]? and which is correct way because currently empty array is coming?

Comment: It means you will not able to change value of files after parsing data from json. It doesn't mean that it will not parse data when it will come from json. If data will come then it will parse them.